# How to navigate to a different page using MenuItem in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter, I have a list of `MenuItems` in `Drawer` like below.

```
 MenuItem selectedMenuItem;
      List<MenuItem> menuItems = [
        MenuItem(title: 'Contact', items: [
          MenuItem(title: 'Contact Us'),
          MenuItem(title: 'Call center'),
          MenuItem(title: 'WhatsApp'),
        ]),
        MenuItem(title: 'language'),
        MenuItem(title: 'Customer'),
      ];
```

I want to open a different page when each item is clicked. What should be my next step? Any ideas?

```
subItems(BuildContext context) {
    return selectedMenuItem.items.map(
      (item) => MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          redirectItem(item);
        },
   
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Text(
              item.title,
           
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Flutter Community! I don't see your complete code so I guess you're already able to perform something when onPressed() is triggered.
You can navigate to another widget using this code:

```
onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => YourWidget(),
          ),
        );
      },
```

Comment: Yes all my items are clickable ,but I want to redirect to different pages according to the clicked item.I could'nt figure out how to do this

Comment: I added to my question @Uni

Comment: @kimSoo I keep on looking at your code and it doesn't make sense. Where is your `onPressed()` when one of your `MenuItems` is clicked?

Comment: For Contact list it's in (item) => MaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          redirectItem(item);
        },

Comment: can you do print(item); in your button and tell me the output?

Comment: It's says myItem Instance of 'MenuItem'

Comment: I don't know what your MenuItem is so I really couldn't help you. You have to identify which MenuItem is being clicked so that you can navigate to a different page based on the identified menuitem. It can be done using a switch statement.

Comment: Navigator.push does not answer question raised